# How can I remove the cylinder from a Bernzomatic QuickFire propane torch?

Tags: soldering

This torch was discontinued by the manufacturer and the division that made it is no longer a part of the company, so current tech support has no knowledge of it. It takes a proprietary propane cylinder about the size of a coffee mug, which twists up into the base.  I cannot remove the cylinder after turning it CCW and pulling fairly hard on it.  Anyone know how to get it out?

[image: Bernzomatic QuickFire]

Comment: Going to have to try harder to unscrew.

Comment: pipe wrench? maybe a squirt of penetrating oil onto the threads overnight?

Answer (score 2):

This torch was discontinued, and finding replacement cylinders will be a chore. I read that the company did have an exchange program at one time, but that was several years ago so that may no longer be an option. You could try calling the Bernzomatic customer service line to see if they still will allow you to return it for credit towards a replacement torch.

The canister may be seized onto the torch, and I would not try to use force to remove it. The contents are under pressure, and may cause an explosion if excessive force is applied. My advice would be to light it and burn off all of the gas in the cylinder, and then safely dispose of it. They sell other torches just like this that accept full size cylinders that have all of the same features. I have had mine for many years and never had any issues.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a small oil filter wrench, I have one for a motorcycle that fits over a propane cylinder , it would probably fit between the bottle and the housing and that would provide more force to unscrew.